# nhibernate3 query - collections with collections

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a few dropdowns in my webpage. These are linked and have a similar class structure with bi-directional linking.

In other words: class Alpha has a list of class Beta which in turn has a list of class Charlie. Each class Beta also has its own list of Alpha (the ones it belongs to) and each class Charlie has its own list of Beta.

I am using NHibernate 3 with fluent nhibernate and automappings.

Now. If I simply would run a

```
session.CreateCriteria<Alpha>().SetMaxResults(1000).List<Alpha>();
```

I get the N+1 problem when I loop over the collections.

The way I see it the following SQL's should be all that's queried to the database

```
select top 1000 * from Alpha
select top 1000 * from Beta
select top 1000 * from Charlie
select * from Alpha2Beta
select * from Beta2Charlie
```

But how do I write the query for this to work??

Comment: You have bidirectional relationships between Alpha and Beta, Beta and Charlie - how can you expect to only query these three tables? There must be linking tables to achieve this...

Comment: Oh silly me, you are absolutely right! I'll update the text

Comment: It sounds like you're using a stateless session. The StatelessSession doesn't have a cache - and, the objects from a stateless session cannot lazily load. This means that you won't be able to pre-fetch the components and do the composite queries. If this is the case - you'll need to use .Fetch() in your queries to eagerly load the sub objects from Alpha2Beta and Beta2Charlie. You will still have some duplication - but not as bad as an N+1.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice trick Ayende showed in his blog. I haven't tried it personally as I decided to change my BL to avoid this problem, so take this with a grain of salt.

You should be able to load collections separately and let NHibernate connect entities, using NHibernate Futures. Since it's not a light subject it's better that you [read his blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate).

Comment: That works after a fashion, but even if you query every Alpha and every Beta, you'll still run into a SELECT N+1 because NH has to query for the Alpha <-> Beta associations.

Comment: Again, I haven't tried it just pointed to resource, but why would you need another N+1 if you load both Alpha and Beta AND join tables? I'm not saying just loading everything would work, but if it doesn't it's because it's not supported, not because it can't be implemented. Of course, this requires some creative mapping :) (mapping join tables)

Comment: If you query the Alphas and Betas, the identity map (L1 cache) will make sure that you don't need to load any Betas when you access the association in an Alpha. However, what doesn't get loaded in the queries is the content of the association table, so what happens when you hit the association is "SELECT FROM Alpha_to_Beta WHERE Alpha_Id = n" instead of "SELECT FROM Alpha_to_Beta INNER JOIN Beta ..." -- that is, if the associations aren't yet loaded, it doesn't help that the entities themselves are pre-loaded. Does that clarify my point at all? :-)

Comment: I understand you completely, but that is not what I was saying :) I was saying that it would be worth taking a shot to map association table (Alpha_to_Beta) beside data tables (Alpha, Beta), and loading all 3 tables to their fullest, NHibernate (!)might make use of loaded Alpha_to_Beta table to join entities. I'm not going to defend this 'maybe' scenario anymore, I was trying to defend principle that this is possible.

Comment: Right, OK. I'm still positing that the technique in the article you linked won't do that -- it works in the example because the Post <-> User association is 1..1, but it won't work with a 1..*. Or rather, it will, but it'll still be SELECT N+1 ;-)

Comment: But if I'm wrong about that, I'll be happy to be enlightened. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Criteria you'll need to include [Dyanmic Fetching](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#querycriteria-dynamicfetching) method calls.

Comment: You can't use dynamic fetching on multiple collections as far as I know. You can fetch multiple related entities and only one collection this way.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way you can help this on a query by query level, like you can with join fetching. However, if you change the *mappings* and set the default fetch mode for the associations to be "subquery", you might be pleasantly surprised:

From the [Hibernate Documentation](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/AShortPrimerOnFetchingStrategies) (works equally well with NHibernate):

> With fetch="subselect" on a collection you can tell Hibernate to not only load this
>   collection in the second SELECT (either lazy or non-lazy), but also all other collections 
>   for all "owning" entities you loaded in the first SELECT. This is especially useful for 
>   fetching multiple collections in parallel"

What this means is that when the first association is required, NHibernate will, instead of loading one association, recall the query you used to get the root entity, then load the association data for all instances of the root entity type that were returned by the query.

That said, if you're loading 1K entities and you expect the associations to have more than a couple of records each, you're probably just going to go from a (SELECT N+1)^2 to a "holy crap I just loaded the entire database into memory". ;-)

(Note that if you do this and have a scenario where you load the Alpha list, but only need the associated Betas for a single Alpha, you're still going to load all of them and there's nothing you can do about that. In practice though, I've found this to be a very rare scenario, so usually subselect fetch suits me very well.)